# Filling combobox with a Linq query

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, visual-studio-2012

I have a combo-box named "CurrencyOne" , I wrote a Linq query

```
 var curren = (from cur in data.MyCurrencys select cur.Value).ToList();
 CurrencyOne.DataContext = curren;
```

and in the xaml fils

```
<ComboBox Name="CurrencyOne"/>
```

how can i make sure that the combo box will be filled with the query result ?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) instead of [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx):

```
var curren = (from cur in data.MyCurrencys select cur.Value).ToList();
CurrencyOne.ItemsSource = curren;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ItemsSource` to list that should be displayed so either set it directly without `DataContext`:

```
var curren = (from cur in data.MyCurrencys select cur.Value).ToList();
CurrencyOne.ItemsSource = curren;
```

or bind `ItemsSource` to current `DataContext`:

```
var curren = (from cur in data.MyCurrencys select cur.Value).ToList();
CurrencyOne.DataContext = curren;

<ComboBox Name="CurrencyOne" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you , it works great knowing that i didn't put the ItemsSource={Binding}